# How do you document in ASA style a journal that the first page is the cover page?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am citing the article Solving the Mystery of Military Mental Health: A Call to Action from this link.

https://www.psychiatrictimes.com/view/solving-mystery-military-mental-health-call-action

My issue is that the first page is the cover page.  The other pages are numbered 1, 2, and 3.

For ASA references, I use page numbers so should I reference it as vol#(issue#):Cover-3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the goal of references is to make it easy for others to find what you are citing. Specific formats and styles just make that more uniform, but the overall goal remains the same. As a consequence, when something doesn't fit a specific style or template, feel free to invent whatever style you think works at identifying where the thing you're referencing can be found.

So, what you propose seems totally fine with me. Or use vol#(issue#):Cover page and pages 1-3. Or anything else that explains what you mean to reference.